# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name id was not found in this ResultSet

Tags: java

Entity Product Class

```
@Entity(name = "product")
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private EProduct name;

    private int priceUnit;

    private int priceWeekend;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="product")
   @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Orders> orders = new HashSet<>();
```

Entity Orders Class

```
Entity(name = "orders")
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Orders {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;


//    @ManyToOne
//    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id",nullable = true)
//    private User user;


@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "product_id", nullable = true)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Product product;




    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate fromDate;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate toDate;

    private int totalPrice;

    private boolean isPaid  = false;
```

Product Repository

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product,Integer> {

  
   @Query(value = "select product.name from product WHERE product.id NOT IN( select product_id FROM orders WHERE from_date = :fromDate and to_date = :toDate)", nativeQuery = true )
    List<Product> findProductsById(@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") @Param("fromDate") LocalDate fromDate, @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") @Param("toDate") LocalDate toDate);
```

Error Message
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name id was not found in this ResultSet.
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.findColumn(PgResultSet.java:2775) ~[postgresql-42.2.24.jar:42.2.24]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getInt(PgResultSet.java:2653) ~[postgresql-42.2.24.jar:42.2.24]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getInt(HikariProxyResultSet.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
at

I dont know what to do

Answer (score 0):

you selected only the name in your query

```
@Query(value = "select product.name from product WHERE product.id NOT IN( select product_id FROM orders WHERE from_date = :fromDate and to_date = :toDate)", nativeQuery = true )
```

insetead you should use

```
@Query(value = "select product from product WHERE product.id NOT IN( select product_id FROM orders WHERE from_date = :fromDate and to_date = :toDate)", nativeQuery = true )
```

Comment: I changed but still the same error

Comment: ok, try this 
@Query(value = "select * from product WHERE product.id NOT IN( select product_id FROM orders WHERE from_date = :fromDate and to_date = :toDate)", nativeQuery = true )
and check if the product table has the id field with the name id

Comment: The query is working all perfect i tested it on postgres